# How to get effect of Task.WhenAny for a Task and CancellationToken?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, cancellation-token

I have interactive task which in "worst" scenario is not executed at all, thus it is represented by `TaskCompletionSource`.

I would like to wait for either this task completes, or token which I received is cancelled -- whichever happens first. Perfect tool for such job would be `Task.WhenAny`, the only problem is it takes only tasks, and I have one `Task` and one `CancellationToken`.

How to wait (asynchronously, like `Task.WhenAny`) for the first event triggered -- completed task, or cancelled token?

```
async Task MyCodeAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<UserData>(); // represents interactive part

  await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, token); // imaginary call

  UserData data = tcs.Task.Result; // user interacted, let's continue
  ...
}
```

*I don't create/manage token, so I cannot change it. I have to deal with it.*

**Update**: For such particular case one could use `Register` method on token to cancel the `TaskCompletionSource`. For more general method please see Matthew Watson answer.

Comment: Post the code. You don't need `WhenAny` to cancel a task, you pass the cancellation token to whatever code you use to create the task. `WhenAny` has nothing to do with this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I added some imaginary code. I am not asking how to cancel the task, I cannot do this, because on one hand I don't control token source, on the second, the actual task is interactive, so there is no code executed when user does not respond.

Comment: What are you going to do if the token is signaled? If you want to cancel the returned task, you can call `SetCancelled` when the token is signaled. If you want to proceed to the *next* line, you need a different mechanism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an extension method that transforms a `CancellationToken` to a `Task` or `Task<TResult>`. The returned task will complete as cancelled immediately after the `CancellationToken` receives a cancellation request.

```
static class CancellationTokenExtensions
{
    public static Task AsTask(this CancellationToken token)
    {
        return new Task(() => throw new InvalidOperationException(), token);
    }

    public static Task<TResult> AsTask<TResult>(this CancellationToken token)
    {
        return new Task<TResult>(() => throw new InvalidOperationException(), token);
    }
}
```

Usage example. Just `await` any task:

```
await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, token.AsTask());
```

...or `await` and get the result in the same line as well:

```
var data = await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, token.AsTask<UserData>()).Unwrap();
```

The `InvalidOperationException` is thrown just in case, to ensure that the task of the `CancellationToken` will never run to completion. Its [`Status`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.status) can only be `Created`, `Canceled` or `Faulted`. On .NET 7 the exception could be the more meaningful [`UnreachableException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.unreachableexception).

Comment: Thank you, however you still need to do something with token. With current code, the token can be triggered yet not observed. Documentation says about the second parameter, i.e. "The CancellationToken that the new task will observe." And you don't observe it :-). See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task__ctor_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Did you test my method and it's not working as intended?

Comment: I owe you a big apology and a big thank you, the explanation in documentation completely misled me. This is the nicest approach IMHO.

Comment: Thank you too! Btw I think that Matthew Watson's [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57868233/11178549) is equally good.

Comment: No doubt, unfortunately I can accept only one answer :-) And mixing handling `IDisposable` with one code is not as straightforward as the approach you showed above. Thus I changed the accepted answer, to more streamlined one (i.e. yours).

Answer (score 6):

You could just create an extra task that returns when the cancel token's wait handle is signalled:

```
var factory = new CancellationTokenSource();
var token   = factory.Token;

await Task.WhenAny(
    Task.Run(() => token.WaitHandle.WaitOne()),
    myTask());
```

(However, be aware that this - while simple - does use up an extra thread, which is clearly not ideal. See later for an alternate solution which doesn't use an extra thread.)

If you want to check which task completed, you will have to keep a copy of the tasks before calling `WhenAny()` so you can compare them to the return value, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var factory = new CancellationTokenSource(1000); // Change to 3000 for different result.
            var token   = factory.Token;
            var task    = myTask();

            var result = await Task.WhenAny(
                Task.Run(() => token.WaitHandle.WaitOne()),
                task);

            if (result == task)
                Console.WriteLine("myTask() completed");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("cancel token was signalled");
        }

        static async Task myTask()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you don't want to waste an entire thread waiting for the cancellation token to be signalled, you can use `CancellationToken.Register()` to register a callback with which you can set the result of a `TaskCompletionSource`:

([Lifted from here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2704))

```
public static Task WhenCanceled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>) s).SetResult(true), tcs);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can then use that as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main()
        {
            var factory = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
            var token   = factory.Token;
            var task    = myTask();

            var result = await Task.WhenAny(
                WhenCanceled(token),
                task);

            if (result == task)
                Console.WriteLine("myTask() completed");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("cancel token was signalled");
        }

        public static Task WhenCanceled(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>) s).SetResult(true), tcs);
            return tcs.Task;
        }

        static async Task myTask()
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a preferable approach for the general case.

Comment: [`WaitOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone) blocks the thread-pool thread, and doing so defeats the purpose of scalability.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I added a version which doesn't use an extra thread.

Comment: Thank you once again, however this time you introduced little bug, you cannot wrap such nicely `Register` because it returns `IDisposable`, so it is better for it to sit within `using`. This is of course just minor remark, because the mechanism in general still holds, I am writing to prevent blind copy&paste for someone.

Comment: The [`Register`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register) method returns a disposable as a mechanism to allow unregistration. AFAIK no harm is done by not disposing it.

Comment: @astrowalker You don't really need to dispose the return value from `Register()` for this SPECIFIC usage, so it's fine. (Of course, it's the same for `Task` objects themselves - they are also disposable, but you rarely see them being disposed either.

Answer (score 5):

With this scenario, you have to be extremely careful about leaks. In particular, having objects referenced by delegates that are registered to a long-lived `CancellationToken`.

The approach that I eventually ended up with in my [AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx) looks like this:

```
public static async Task<T> WaitAsync<T>(this Task<T> task, CancellationToken token)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
  using (token.Register(() => tcs.TrySetCanceled(token), useSynchronizationContext: false)
    return await await Task.WhenAny(task, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

The code above ensures that the registration is disposed if the `CancellationToken` is not canceled.

Usage:

```
async Task MyCodeAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
  UserData data = await userDataTask.WaitAsync(token);
}
```

Comment: When you use double `await`, don't you need double `ConfigureAwait(false)` also?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: No. The inner `await` may behave asynchronously, so it needs `ConfigureAwait(false)`. The resulting value is a task *that has already completed*, so adding a `ConfigureAwait(false)` on the outer `await` would have no effect.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary could you pls explain the use of the double await here? Thx

Comment: @pasx: `Task.WhenAny` returns a `Task<Task<T>>` - i.e., a task that will complete with the first task that completed. So the inner `await` just waits for either task to complete, and the outer `await` gets the result (or propagates the exception) of that task.