# Guaranteeing serial task execution with Rx when using Observable.FromAsync and the Switch operator?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive

I'm trying to use `Observable.FromAsync()` in combination with `Switch()` to execute a task until a new notification comes in, something a bit like this:

```
public static async void Main(string[] args)
{
    var pump = Observable.Range(0, 3);
    var sub = pump.Select(_ => Observable.FromAsync(ct => Run(ct, _))).Switch();
    await sub.ToTask();
}

private static async Task Run(CancellationToken ct, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Started {i}");
    while (true) await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // note not using ct on purpose
}
```

This prints:

```
Started 0
Started 1
Started 2
```

But this is not quite what I want. I would like the tasks produced by the `FromAsync()` call to only ever be executed serially and exclusively, so in the case where the task does not support cancellation (or the cancellation is very slow) I want the output to be just:

```
Started 0
```

In effect, the observable should now become blocked until the previous task has completed.

I know `Concat()` can be used instead of `Switch()` to remove parallelism in this situation, but the semantic of this is different; it won't unsubscribe from the current observable and so the cancellation token will not get revoked and the task cannot gracefully stop. It's important that we try to cancel the token so I can wind down the task, not just replace it.

**Note**: If we amend `Run()` to pass the cancellation token to the `Task.Delay()` call we see it outputs the same three lines, which is desired.

My workaround at the moment involves using a semaphore in the `Run()` method, this is simple but not ideal. I feel like I should be able to solve this at the Rx layer.

Comment: The phrase *task not obeying revocation of the cancellation token* is a bit unclear. Do you mean that your tasks do not support cancellation? If yes, would it be a solution to use cancelable wrappers around the non-cancelable tasks?

Comment: Fair point, I'll edit the text to simplify but, yes in this case the tasks might never cancel (as in my example) or maybe that they are just very slow to cancel. I think I'm less worried about making sure they can be cancelled (in the real world, they should cancel just fine), rather I want to guarantee that the next task *will not* start until the previous task has completed AND doing this with the semantics of Switch(), where the token is canclled so the tear down is cleaner.

Comment: I checked out that your code behaves desirably by using `Concat` instead of `Switch`. `Concat` is evaluated lazily, while `Switch` is not. So I think that by using `Concat` combined with instantly cancelable tasks you'll get the guarantees you want. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868078/how-to-get-effect-of-task-whenany-for-a-task-and-cancellationtoken/57870110#57870110) for a way to create cancelable wrappers of tasks.