# Task.waitAny functionality for awaitables

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm currently running into a race condition due to waiting for 0.25 seconds in an async function. A cancellation token is checked in the loop, but happens late due to the wait.

I'm using a library that provides 'Await.Until' functionality, which allows for awaiting boolean values. As such I considered waiting for either 0.25 seconds, or token.isCancelled to be true.

I'm sure outsourcing them to separate tasks, and then using Task.waitAny() would work, but it seems a little over the top. Is there a more elegant way to await multiple awaitables?

```
while (!Completed)
{
    Completed = AdjustPath();

    await Await.Seconds(PathingDelay);

    if (!loop) 
        return Completed;
    else if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        StopMove();

        return false;
    }
}
```

The issue above is that the containing function is called again, which sets a destination, before the cancellation is resolved, which stops the object and removes the destination. While I could await the task finishing, that would add a delay to the method running, which is not ideal.

Comment: Have a look at Task.Delay which takes an optional CancellationToken

Comment: Unfortunately, (For this specific problem) Task.Delay doesn't return control and pass the await when cancelled, and thus does not execute the necessary functionality for interruption.

As far as I know, await can't be in a try catch statement, but task.wait can be (though blocks the thread). I'm not sure if that'll work, but I'll give it a try in a bit.

Comment: Await can be in a catch block since C# 6 and could always be in a try block.

Comment: You are indeed correct according to the docs. I'm not sure where I saw that it couldn't.

Comment: Possibly related: [How to get effect of Task.WhenAny for a Task and CancellationToken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57868078/how-to-get-effect-of-task-whenany-for-a-task-and-cancellationtoken/)

Answer (score 1):

With a `TaskCompletionSource<T>` you can build a `Task` that will complete when a cancellation is requested by a given `CancellationToken`.

```
public static class Async
{
    private static readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> _neverComplete = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    public static Task CompleteOnCancellation( CancellationToken token )
    {
        if ( !token.CanBeCanceled )
            return _neverComplete.Task;
        if ( token.IsCancellationRequested )
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        token.Register( () => tcs.SetResult( true ) );

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `Task.WhenAny` to interrupt the waiting delay

```
using var cts = new CancellationTokenSource( 100 );

var longWaitingTask = Task.Delay( 250 );
var cancellationTask = Async.CompleteOnCancellation( cts.Token );

var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny( longWaitingTask, cancellationTask );

if ( completedTask == longWaitingTask )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Long Running Task completed." );
}
if ( completedTask == cancellationTask )
{
    Console.WriteLine( "Cancellation Task completed." );
}
```

Comment: While this looks more elegant than the other solution, I'm not sure it works in this specific instance, as there doesn't seem to be a way to remove the registered delegates from the token, and the token is only renewed when it's cancelled.

This seems like it would result in multiple of the same delegate being assigned to the token, and excess calls of "StopMove()" being run. It's not an issue in functionality, but it seems like bad practice.

It may however be viable to renew the token when a task chain has finished. That doesn't pose any problems I can see in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Delay(TimeSpan, CancellationToken)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Delay_System_TimeSpan_System_Threading_CancellationToken_), like Dmitry already proposed in his comment.

```
while (!Completed)
{
    Completed = AdjustPath();

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(PathingDelay, token);
    }
    catch(TaskCanceledException e){} // if delay was cancelled is checked in next lines

    if (!loop) 
        return Completed;
    else if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        StopMove();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cancelling the delay seems to return the entire function as I believe it throws an exception. This isn't ideal either as it precludes calling StopMove() on cancellation.

Am I correct in this assessment?